# How to copy or download artifacts in GitLab to another server?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to copy or download artifacts generated in a particular job in GitLab to a remote server using command. How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is quite vague and there are million of options. Would be better if you clarify your architecture. What is the remote server, which OS, where is hosted, how many of those are there, are there any firewalls in between, do you have multiple environements?

Comment: @Shi Do you have any more details about this, as requested by Ivan?

Comment: @Iavn,VonC - The OS in linux. I am actually using AWS (serverless )hence not sure of the rest of the info.

Comment: Do you mean GitlLab is running on AWS? Which version of GitLab? And what is the destination of your copy? What is the remote server?

Comment: All the set up is in Gitlab CI/CD in serverless.yml. It deploys the code as a lamda function on AWS. Since it's serverless, the artefacts generested (as .zip) are saved in a S3 bucket. How do I save these artefacts in another location of my choice? or if there's any way to download it in my local machine?

Comment: @Shivani I will check, but it would help if you can edit your question and add as much details as you can.